# Cosmos User kit template not showing up in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, vb.net, cosmos

I recently installed cosmos user kit and it is not showing up in visual studio 2019. It doesn't even show up in the visual studio templates folder. I have tried reinstalling cosmos several times. It doesn't work.
Some help required

Comment: Did you build? Was build successful?  https://www.gocosmos.org/docs/install/?force_isolation=true

Comment: No I couldn't build because it didn't show up in Visual Studio

Comment: Ure you did everything in Link? Did you read Prerequisites?

Comment: @Superfudge2020, Any update on this? Please answer yourself if your found the solution. I am running into same issue with vs2022. Somebody please help.